# How to create table headers in a dynamically sized table using Angularjs

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, html-table

I want to create a dynamic height & width table, but I'm having trouble with the table header.

The `<td>` elements display just fine with this `ng-repeat`er

```
<tr ng-repeat="set in currFormData.volume track by $index">
  <td ng-repeat="repSpace in set track by $index">
    {{repSpace}}
  </td>
</tr>
```

but I want a `<th>` row containing `1, 2, 3, 4...` and it must adjust as the table adjusts. I'm looking for something like this which looks through only the second level of my model 1 time:

```
<tr>
  <th ng-repeat="repSpace in set in currFormData.volume track by $index">{{$index + 1}}</th>
</tr>
```

Here is my `$scope` model:

```
$scope.currFormData = {"date" : "", "volume": [
    [[1,135],[0,0],[0,0],[0,0],[0,0],[0,0],[0,0],[0,0],[0,0],[0,0],[0,0],[0,0]],
    [[0,0],[0,0],[0,0],[0,0],[0,0],[0,0],[0,0],[0,0],[0,0],[0,0],[0,0],[0,0]],
    [[0,0],[0,0],[0,0],[0,0],[0,0],[0,0],[0,0],[0,0],[0,0],[0,0],[0,0],[0,0]],
    [[0,0],[0,0],[0,0],[0,0],[0,0],[0,0],[0,0],[0,0],[0,0],[0,0],[0,0],[0,0]]
] };
```

**How can I make this work?** I'm open to changing my model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that every 'set' in your 'volume' will be of equal length:

HTML:

```
<th ng-repeat="i in getArray(currFormData.volume[0].length) track by $index">{{$index + 1}}</th>
```

Controller:

```
$scope.getArray = function (length) {
    return new Array(length);
}
```

Otherwise:

HTML:

```
<th ng-repeat="i in getLongestArray(currFormData.volume) track by $index">{{$index + 1}}</th>
```

Controller:

```
$scope.getLongestArray = function (arrayOfArrays) {
    var longest: number = 0;
    for (var i: number = 0; i < arrayOfArrays.length; i++) {
        if (arrayOfArrays[i].length > longest) {
            longest = arrayOfArrays[i].length;
        }
    }
    return (new Array(longest));
}
```